# error no set to EIO while using pwrite() API

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have remote disks mounted on my system using NFS and I am trying to write to the files on the mounted remote disks using pwrite() API.

It doesn't happen every time but in some cases while doing I/O pwrite() fails and set the error number to EIO(Input/Output error).

Can some one please explain why this error occur on the first place and is there any way I can correct it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified with a minimal test program (say, writing random-length blocks at random offsets to a fixed-size target file) that exhibits the problem? Usually `EIO` only happens due to a bug (like descriptor already closed) or a real read/write error on the underlying device or file system. In some cases `pwrite()` may rely on `lseek()` (on the client or server), and it is feasible then that a collision by two concurrent writers might end up as `errno` == `EIO`. With a small test case, run on two different clients concurrently writing to the same file, you could easily verify.

Comment: Yes, I am doing I/O at random offset locations in a file only. But it's only one thread as of now that is doing I/O using pwrite() to the files on the mounted servers(no concurrent write operation on a single file). And I am sure that the file descriptor isn't closed. Can it be a problem with NFS interface ?

Comment: Yes, most probably. Anyhow, as I ran into such an `EIO` issue, `NFS` logging never showed any errors .... :-( @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 0):

From (bad) experiences with reading and writing to `NFS` based files I learned that you have a good chance to work around  this `EIO` by simply retrying the failed I/O operation (`read()`, `write()`).

Also on `NFS` one can not assume that `read()`/`write()` do transfer the amount of data specified, so it is good idea to always check the return value of the function in question on how many byte were transfered.

I see the issue in the underlying `NFS` functionality or in the way the `NFS` driver's results are handled by the kernel, so I strongly assume `pread()`/`pwrite()` show the same effects as I witnessed when using `read()`/`write()`.